# Is cockpit using a different time zone for automatic updates?

Tags: fedora, timezone, automatic-updates, cockpit

I have configured the cockpit web console on my fedora server to automatically install updates at 04:00 every day. I am in the CEST time zone, so 02:00 UTC. It also makes the server reboot after installing the updates.

The behaviour I expected was that my server would reboot a little after 04:00, but it rebooted at 22:00 (10pm), which isn't the time I specified whether it's interpreted as CEST or UTC. It is 6 hours earlier than I expected, and would correspond to EDT, which I don't use.

After checking with `timedatectl`, I have confirmed that my server's RTC is on time and that it is in the correct time zone.

I haven't found documentation relating to this and there doesn't appear to be an option in the web console either. For the time being I've set the update time to 10:00 to compensate for the offset.